# How can i save one frame each time from a video stream to the flash card on my device?

Tags: android, eclipse

Im using this code to open the Camera video mode on my device:

```
package com.example.camera_test;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Video;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337; 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
            Intent videoIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult( videoIntent,0);
```

And it's working good when clicking a button it will open the camera on a video.
Now I want to get a video stream and not to record/save the video to the device disk but to get each time in real time one frame from the video save this frame to the flash memory card do something with the frame delete it after did something with it then the next frame and so on...

So in the end when im moving my device around left right up down everywhere around it will all the time save one frame from the video to the flash memory do something and delete it and so on.

Frame I mean one image wich is a frame. To extract the current frame to the flash memory do something and delete this frame and the next one.

How can I start thinking and doing it ?

Comment: Saving each frame as a separate image will end up generating WAY more data, FAR faster, than writing out a video file. Is there any reason you can't possibly split out the frames later?

Comment: later when ? after saving the video ? but if I put the camera to work for 30 minutes or so it will save a very large video file to my device.

Comment: The image files will be many times larger than the video. What do you need the frames for? (More generally: What are you trying to do here?)

Comment: I need the frames first to make get an histogram of each frame. So I don't want to save all the frames from the video like images or video file I want to save each time from the video one frame in the flash memory make histogram of it keep the histogram then delete the frame from the flsh memory card then the next frame and so on.In the end I want to have a list of histograms or something so each time I activate the video it will start making histograms. Late on I want to use this histograms but first this is the process I need the frames for.

Comment: If that's the case, writing the image to the flash card seems like an unnecessary intermediate step. You'd probably rather just generate the histogram from the video data without writing the frames anywhere.

Comment: How can I get or process the video data ? Do I need to start recording for that ? Or I can get the live video data while the camera video mode is on ?

Answer (score 0):

You display a preview of the video feed, then call Camera.takePicture to get a callback with a byte array for the data for the frame at the time you call that. There's a good example of setting up everything on the Android Developer site:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture

Please note that on the developer site it has a button that triggers the takePicture call, but you can call from code just as easily. Based on the parameters supplied, you can receive either a compressed JPEG version of the frame or a raw data version. If you are going to save to SD card as a JPEG, it is more efficient to let the system do the compression. If you need more than one frame, setup the same program as per the developer guide, but then use the Camera#setPreviewCallback method to get a callback for every single frame of the video feed.